# forbidden message while executing a rest message through Jmeter

Tags: rest, truclient

We have come across similar problem, need your help to resolve this.
Can you please either let us know your contact number so that we can reach out to you or if you can provide your script if possible so that we can refer to

Here is the problem we are stuck with:
I am trying to test a Rest service through HTTP sampler using Jmeter. Not sure how to capture token from the sampler generates a token and to use this token for authorization in the header manager of another HTTP.

Loadrunner is not displaying the web address when trying to enter in the truclient browser. Below is the problem as this web address automatically redirect to another web address which is the authentication server.

Can you please suggest another solution for the below issue?
Here is the exact scenario we are trying to achieve 
 we want to loadtest the portal however due to redirect and different authentication method being used we are unable to do it using truclient protocol in loadrunner. Also tried Multiple protocol selecting LDAP, SMTP, HTTP/HTML etc but no luck.**

Thank You, 
Sonny

Comment: add some code so that anyone can visualize your problem.

Answer (score 0):

JMETER is going to architecturally be the HTTP protocol layer equivalent with LoadRunner, with the exception of the number of threads per browser emulation.

In contrast to the code request, I want to architecturally visualize the problem.   You mention redirect, is this an HTTP 301/302 redirect or one which is handled with information passed back to the client, processed on the client and then redirected to another host?   You mention dynamic authentication via header token, have you examined the web_add_header() and web_add_auto_header() in Laodrunner web virtual users for passing of extra header messages, including ones which have been correlated from previous requests, such as the token being passed back as you note?

This authentication mechanism is based upon?  LDAP?  Kerberos?  Windows Integrated Authentication?  Simple Authentication based upon username/password in header?  Can you be architecturally more specific and when this comes into play, such as from the first request to gain access to the test environment through the firewall or from a *n*th request to gain access within a business process?

You mention RESTFul services.  These can be transport independent, such as being passed over SMTP using a mailbox to broker the passing of data between client and server, or over HTTP similar to SOAP messages.   Do you have architectural clarity on this?  Could it be that you need to provide mailbox authentication across SMTP and POP3 to send and receive?